# Logarithms and Reciprocals

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Show that the integral of $(e^x + e^{-x})/ (e^x -e^{-x})$ equals $\ln(1-e^{2x})-x+c$. I reached the stage where $\ln(e^{-2x} -1 ) +c$, but I don't know how to get the $-x$ and how to reverse the signs to make $1$ positive and $e^{-2x}$ negative.

Comment: $\ln (1 - e^{2x} ) - x = \ln (1 - e^{2x} ) + \ln e^{ - x}  = \ln ((1 - e^{2x} )e^{ - x} ) = \ln (e^{ - x}  - e^x )$, but you have to assume that $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$ \cosh(x) = \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2} $$
and
$$ \sinh(x)=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2} $$

Knowing this then,

$$ I = \int \frac{\cosh(x)}{\sinh(x)} dx = \int \frac{1}{u} du = \ln(u) + C$$

Here, we've used $u=\sinh(x)$ and similarly,

$$I = \ln \left( \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} \right) + C = \ln \left( \frac{e^x}{2} \cdot \left( 1 - e^{-2x} \right) \right) + C$$

Last step,

$$I = \ln \left( 1 - e^{-2x} \right) + x - \ln \left( 2 \right) +C$$

Answer (score 0):

What needs to be kept in mind when dealing with the anti-derivative for $ \ \frac{e^x \ + \ e^{-x}}{e^x \ - \ e^{-x}} \ = \ \coth x \ $ is that this is an odd function that is discontinuous at $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  So the complication in manipulating expressions for the anti-derivative function is that the sign of $ \ x \ $ matters.

An analogy can be made with $ \ \int \ \frac{1}{x} \ \ dx \ \ . \ $ Since this integrand is positive for $ \ x \ > \ 0 \ $ and negative for $ \ x \ < \ 0 \ \ , \ $ we have
$$   \int \ \frac{1}{x} \ \ dx \ \ = \ \ \left\{ \ \begin{array}{rcl}
\ln \ x \ + \ C \ \ ,  & x \ > \ 0 \\   \ln \ (-x) \ + \ C \ \ ,  & x \ < \ 0
\end{array}\right. \ \  \ , $$
which may be condensed into $ \ \ln \ |x| \ + \ C \ \ $ for its domain $ \ \mathbb{R} - \{0\} \ \ . $  This is an even function, as we should expect, and its derivative correctly produces the "behavior" of $ \ \frac{1}{x} \ \ . \ $

For $ \ \int \ \frac{e^x \ + \ e^{-x}}{e^x \ - \ e^{-x}} \ \ dx \ = \ \int \ \coth x \ \ dx \ \ , \ $ we must also accommodate the odd symmetry of the integrand, which has the same "sign-behavior" as $ \ \frac{1}{x} \ \ , \ $ leading us to write
$$   \int \ \coth x \ \ dx \ \ = \ \ \left\{ \ \begin{array}{rcl}
\ln \ ( \sinh x) \ + \ C \ \ ,  & x \ > \ 0 \\   \ln \ ( -\sinh x) \ + \ C \ \ ,  & x \ < \ 0
\end{array}\right. \ \ = \ \ \ln \ | \sinh x | \ + \ C \ \ , $$
which is an even function over $ \ \mathbb{R} - \{0\} \ \ . $

This is manifested in how the anti-derivative must be expressed when the integral is written as $ \ \int \ \frac{e^x \ + \ e^{-x}}{e^x \ - \ e^{-x}} \ \ dx \ \ . \ $  The "raw" result from applying $ \ u \ = \ e^x \ - \ e^{-x} \ \ , \ \ du \ = \ (e^x \ - \ e^{-x}) \ dx \ $ $ \rightarrow \ \int \ \frac{du}{u} \ \rightarrow \ \ln \ (e^x \ - \ e^{-x}) \ + \ C \ $ produces a function which is only defined for $ \ x \ > \ 0 \ \ . \ $  So to extend the anti-derivative function over  $ \ \mathbb{R} - \{0\} \ \ , \ $ we would give the general result as $ \ \ln \ |e^x \ - \ e^{-x}| \ + \ C \ \ .  $

This brings us to the matter of how we are to obtain the particular expression shown in the original problem.  With $ \ x \ > \ 0 \ , \ $ we can write $$ \ln \ (e^x \ - \ e^{-x}) \ \ = \ \ \ln \ ( \ e^x · [1 \ - \ e^{-2x}] \ ) \ \ = \ \ \ln \ (  1 \ - \ e^{-2x}  ) \ + \ \ln \ (   e^x   ) $$ $$ =  \ \ \ln \ (  1 \ - \ e^{-2x}  ) \ + \ x \ \ , \ $$
each expression being defined for this interval.  However, for $ \ x \ < \ 0 \ , \ $ because we are working with the absolute-value of a difference, we instead  factor this as
$$ \ln \ ( \ -[e^x \ - \ e^{-x}] \ ) \ \ = \ \ \ln \ ( \ e^{-x} · [1 \ - \ e^{2x}] \ ) \ \ = \ \ \ln \ (  1 \ - \ e^{2x}  ) \ + \ \ln \ (   e^{-x}   ) $$ $$ =  \ \ \ln \ (  1 \ - \ e^{2x}  ) \ - \ x \ \ , \ $$
each expression being defined in *this* interval.  (This is as described in **Gary**'s  comment to the OP.)

There is one discrepancy to be resolved, in that this is not entirely consistent with our integration of hyperbolic cotangent.  Applying the definition of hyperbolic sine, we have
$$  \ln \ ( \sinh x) \ \ = \ \ \ln  \left( \frac{e^x \ - \ e^{-x}}{2} \right) \ \ = \ \ \ln  \left( \frac{1 \ - \ e^{-2x}}{2·e^{-x}} \right) \ \ = \ \ \ln  \left( \frac{e^{2x} \ - \ 1}{2·e^x} \right) \ \ , \  $$
producing the complete anti-derivative function as

$$   \int \ \frac{e^x \ + \ e^{-x}}{e^x \ - \ e^{-x}} \ \ dx \ \ = \ \ \left\{ \ \begin{array}{rcl}
\ln \ (  1 \ - \ e^{-2x}  ) \ + \ x \ - \ \ln \ 2 \ + \ C \ \ ,  & x \ > \ 0 \\  \ln \ (  1 \ - \ e^{2x}  ) \ - \ x \ - \ \ln \ 2 \ + \ C \ \ ,  & x \ < \ 0
\end{array}\right.  $$
[the first "branch" of this is shown by **SNR**].

So the anti-derivative stated in the problem is only applicable for $ \ x \ < \ 0 \ $ (as **Gary** remarks); the $ \ \ln 2 \ $ term can be "absorbed" into the integration constant $ \ C \ \ , \ $ as so often occurs with general anti-derivative functions for circular (trigonometric) functions.